# Iterate a list on a specific range of indexes and get the elements of the sub-lists in these indexes

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to iterate through a list of lists, only on a specific range of indexes which are given from another list, and get the elements of the sublists in those indexes only

I created a list comprehension that reads a list of lists: *common_a[ ]* then I need to iterate over a specific range of indexes of this list( the range is the range of indexes of the *hits_idx1[ ]* list) in order to further use the the contents of the sub lists under those indexes:

```
hits_idx1 = [5,4] # use the indexes of this list as a range [0,1]
common_a = [[23],[3,8,2,5],[2,1]] # iterate on the [0,1] range indexes only


s = [ [ data_db[0][x] for x in common_a[] ],
      [ data_db[2][x] for x in common_a[] ],
      [ ....                              ]  ]
```

I cannot rap my head around how to iterate over the specific range of indexes, i need something like the following:

```
[ data_db[0][x] for x in common_a[ [index for index, value in enumerate(hit_idx1)] ]
```

but it doesnt work as this produces a list, so i tried to iterate over the produced list of indices:

```
[ data_db[0][x] for x in common_a[y] for y in [0,1] ]
```

But it doesn't work, after many combinations of the above and many hours i am stuck any help,suggestion is very welcome thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the following **nested list comprehension** where you directly iterate over the `hits_idx1` to get the index and then pass it to `common_a` to get the sublist at that corresponding index. You then iterate over that sublist to use its elements in `data_db`

Without having access to sample input and desired output, it's all contemplative right now. Give the following code a try and let me know in the comments, if it works and if any changes are required.

```
hits_idx1 = [5,4] # use the indexes of this list as a range [0,1]
common_a = [[23],[3,8,2,5],[2,1]]

desired = [data_db[0][x] for ind in hit_idx1 for x in common_a[ind]]
```

Comment: I tried it but it complains _that `ind` is not identified_ , isn't there a way to enclose the iteration inside the brackets of `common_a[ ind for ind in hit_idx1         ]` ?

Comment: @Artemis: Try my edited version. I switched the order of for loops.

Comment: @Artemis: Did it work? I don't think `common_a[ ind for ind in hit_idx1 ]` will work. I tried it for a sample list and it didn't